# Convert datetime to just date in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

I want to select a datetime stamp column from a table, but select it just in date format. I tried `SELECT TO_CHAR(Column,'MM/DD/YY')` but it did not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use `trunc()`:

```
select trunc(column)
```

This removes the time component in Oracle.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.  I am using Crystal Reports with oracle db.

Comment: @Chemdawg . . . Are you sure you are using Oracle?  For instance, if you are really using MySQL, then `date(col)` should work.